# C++/C Arduino Stopwatch code check

Tags: arduino

I'm making a stopwatch with an arduino with a vibration motor and a simple button as the interface.

I'm coming to a hold with this project as it just won't work, i've been testing it on my uno with no success so far, I was wondering if someone could give me a quick little run-down and see if they can spot any big issues that i've overlooked.

No errors in code, I think it might be a logical error on my behalf or possibly even an error with my board, but I doubt that!

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
int lengthOf(int i)
{
    if (i < 0){i = -i;}
    if (i < 10){ return 1;}
    if (i < 100){ return 2;}
    if (i < 1000){ return 3;}
    if (i < 10000){ return 4;}
    if (i < 100000){ return 5;}
    if (i < 1000000){ return 6;}
    if (i < 10000000){ return 7;}
    if (i < 100000000){ return 8;}
    if (i < 1000000000){ return 9;}
    return 10;
}
void loop() {

    int ButtonSwitch = 4;
    pinMode(4, INPUT);
    int motor = 5;
    int timerA = 0;   int timed; 
    bool checker = false; //checker acts to see if the current state is timing/counting
    bool shown; //Shown acts as a check to show if the time has already been shown

    if (analogRead(ButtonSwitch) == HIGH && checker == false)//When the button is pressed and the state is false then 
    {
        checker = true;//sets checker to true, meaning the timing should begin
        shown = false;//sets the shown variable to false so as to 
        timerA = 0;//reset timer to a 0 value
    }

    while (checker == true)//while the timer is active then do the following
    {
        timerA++;//Increment the timer 
        if (digitalRead(ButtonSwitch) == HIGH)
        {
            checker = false;
            break;
        }
        delay(1000);//No needfor the simpleTimer library as I don't need to run any code inbetween each second
    }

    //Sets the timed to the real value of
    timed = lengthOf(timerA);//Grabs the length of timerA (1223 would be 4)
    int recTime[timed - 1]; //creates an array of the same length as the timer


    //append int to chars and by extent an array
    char str[timed];
    sprintf(str, "%d", timerA);

    int numbers;

    for (int i = 0;  i < timed; i++)
    {
        recTime[i] = str[i] - '0';//This grabs STR which is an empty array of the length of the time then sets recTime to be the same
    }

    while ((analogRead(ButtonSwitch) == LOW) && (checker == false) && (shown == false))//Loop checks that the button is not pressed, the checker is false, and that the time has not been shown,
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < timed; i++)//
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < recTime[i]; o++)
            {
                digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);//Motor set to vibrate
                delay(500);//1/2 second delay
                digitalWrite(motor, LOW);//motor off
                delay(300);//3/10 second delay
            }
            delay(3000);//3 second delay
        }
        shown = true;
    }
}
```

If there's any more info I can provide then let me know,

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem when you say "it just won't work"? any errors you see?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - No output of any kind, code is perfectly functional as far as I can tell, but when I set up my circuits with the motor and button there's no action happening.

Comment: This is no debugging service. And Arduino is definitively not C and not exactly C++.

Comment: Alright sure, could you point me in the right direction then? I'm fairly new to programming and using arduino and my research prior to this was pointing to stackoverflow being the right place. I'll delete the thread if need be.

Comment: There are some bugs or strange things. You first do `analogRead` and then `digitalRead`. Compare analogRead with HIGH(¿?). If you read the button and, a few lines down, read again probably you hadn't time to release button, so `while(check...` only do one iteration; so timerA = 1... Read again your code very slow and simulate it in your mind. Moreover, use `pinMode` only once in `setup` Now Im in my job, I can't rewrite your code but it need a lot of rethinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read through your code and have a few suggestions. First, let's be consistent and use a digitalRead instead of the analogRead near the top and bottom of the loop routine. Let's move all of your variable declarations before the setup routine. (you will still need to initialize timerA, checker and shown at the top of loop) Also, you only need to set the pinMode for the button once, so we'll move that line to the setup routine and, while we're at it, let's use the variable ButtonSwitch in the pinMode command. e.g.

```
int ButtonSwitch = 4;
int motor = 5;
int timerA = 0;
int timed; 
bool checker = false;
bool shown;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ButtonSwitch, INPUT);
}
```

But I think the real problem could be with the logical flow of the program. Assume the loop starts, checker is false and the button is not pressed. When you press the button, checker gets set to true. Immediately after that, within a few clocks ticks, the next block is entered (because checker is true) and it sets checker to false and exits the block if the button is still being pressed. The chances of you releasing the button between the first block and the second is pretty much zero. So your program just keeps setting timerA to 0, then incrementing it by 1 and moving on. The delay(1000) is never reached and timerA never gets above 1, the recTime array will always be defined as recTime[0] and the str array will always be defined as str[1].

In the second block, the while loop, I think you want to change 
if (digitalRead(ButtonSwitch) == HIGH) to if (digitalRead(ButtonSwitch) == LOW).

I think if you rectify these issues, you'll be a long way towards getting git working!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've just made some of the changes you suggested, should I then add the delay to the beginning of the `while(checker == true)` ? It seems to me as though that will help solve the issue you spotted.

Comment: It would give you time to release the button. But if your intent to time the length of the button press, I think that just making the change I mentioned above (changing "if (digitalRead(ButtonSwitch) == HIGH)" to "if (digitalRead(ButtonSwitch) == LOW)" should do the trick.

Comment: Ahh I understand! Making these changes now, will test and update.

Answer (score 0):

In C, when `timed` is the number of chars needed to write the decimal digits of a number, then you should allocate one more for the terminating `'\0'`.

```
char str[timed+1];
```

Then, I'm wondering what you're doing with the `recTime` values. Indeed, whenever for a value of `123`, str would contain `"123"`, i.e. `['1','2','3']`, then retTime would contain `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Hi Didier, i've just made the `timed` change, thanks for that!

the reason for the recTime is that I wasn't sure if '1' could be handled as an int, so I just converted it in case. Do you think it's pointless doing so?

Comment: @user3068449 I'm wondering why in the loop at the end of the program, you'd want to make 1 loop, then 2 loops, and then 3 loops if the value is 123?

Comment: Okay so the thinking behind that is that the first one is a check to see if it's time to turn the motor on, I should change this to an if. The second is for the length of the number (19292 is 5 long), while the third is to set vibrate the the amount of times of the value of the previous loop (round 2 vibrates 9 times), does that make sense?